# How to merge multiple Qt Creator UI's using Git

Tags: git, qt, merge, qt-creator, merge-conflict-resolution

I and several other people are working on a GUI using QT 5. We are each working on separate pages of the UI file and we would like to merge them all together; however we get merge conflicts when trying to merge using git pull.

To my understanding, Qt 5 does not let you touch the actual source code for the "file.ui" file and only lets you change the appearance in Design mode. Is there a way to merge the different UI versions without having to manually copy and paste buttons and pages onto a single UI, push that UI to the file, and have that file overwrite our separate working files?

Comment: _Qt 5 does not let you touch the actual source code for the "file.ui"_ Not really, you can open `.ui` in text mode, its an XML file

Answer (score 0):

To generate .ui files qt uses the uic (ui-compiler). The actual contents of the ui file are .xml, but the qt designer editor does this for you and i dont recommend  trying to hack it. But if you must, merge the .xml.